# Caching authenticated resources using Varnish

Tags: authentication, caching, resources, vcl, varnish

Our firm uses an application internally that serves more or less static content to all authenticated users. The application is built such that all its resources (js, css, images, html pages) are authenticated. Sadly, I can't seem to get Varnish working for caching authenticated resources. If I make the resource unauthenticated and use the following VCL configuration, things work:

```
backend default {
  .host = "****";
  .port = "****";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/js" || req.url ~ "^/css" || req.url ~ "^/images") {
            unset req.http.cookie;
    }    
}
sub vcl_fetch {
    if (req.url ~ "^/js" || req.url ~ "^/css" || req.url ~ "^/images") {
            unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }
}
```

However, I'm looking to cache despite the resource being authenticated which I understand is not Varnish's default behaviour. Trying

```
if (req.http.Authorization) {
        return(lookup);
}
```

in vcl_recv hasn't helped. Unsetting Authorization headers doesn't help either (application's authentication gets messed up).

I get the following varnish logs (b- backend calls still happen):

```
14 TxURL        b /_search
14 TxHeader     b Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
15 RxURL        c /_search
15 RxHeader     c Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
14 TxURL        b /admin
14 TxHeader     b Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
17 RxURL        c /admin
17 RxHeader     c Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
15 RxURL        c /_search
15 RxHeader     c Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
17 RxURL        c /admin
17 RxHeader     c Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
14 TxURL        b /js/all.js?_=1385100392830
17 RxURL        c /js/all.js?_=1385100392830
```

Adding the HTTP request and response headers:

**Request Headers:**

```
Host: ****.com
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Negotiate YIIVTAYGKwYBBQUCoIIVQDCCFTygMDAuBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKK
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
Referer: ****
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

**Response Headers:**

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Sat, 10 Nov 2012 08:32:01 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "{6B28BC5E-71C3-4A1B-9D3C-1DA5EA161F96},2pub"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: 8864bca5-d7cb-4ac0-bbe8-3a64391ca70f
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYGzMIGwoAMKAQChCwYJKoZIgvcSAQICooGbBIGYYIGVBgkqhkiG9xIBAgICAG+BhTCBgqADAgEFoQMCAQ+idjB
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6137
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2013 15:43:46 GMT
```

Can someone please provide me a VCL config snippet that can help?

Comment: Are you using HTTP basic authentication (as req.http.Authorization header suggest) or cookie based authentication (as req.http.cookie suggest) or a combination of both?

Comment: We use kerberos authentication and not HTTP basic authentication. Cookies are used merely to track user preferences and not for authentication.

Comment: Please provide your full VCL file, especially vcl_recv, vcl_hash and vcl_fetch. Also the HTTP headers (sanitizaed) of a full request will be usefull

Comment: Currently we're using the default vcl_recv, vcl_hash, vcl_fetch implementations. Added the HTTP request and response headers in the post.